# "undefined method `session_token' for nil:NilClass" in ruby on rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I've been working on some web app in ruby on rails, and then when I go to : **localhost:3000**
I get this error :

```
undefined method `session_token' for nil:NilClass

if (user_id = session[:user_id])
       user = User.find_by(id: user_id)             
       @current_user ||= user if session[:session_token] == user.session_token
```

The red marker is on this line :

```
        @current_user ||= user if session[:session_token] == user.session_token
```

The completel current_user method is this :

```
def current_user
        if (user_id = session[:user_id])
            user = User.find_by(id: user_id)            
            @current_user ||= user if session[:session_token] == user.session_token         
        elsif (user_id = cookies.encrypted[:user_id])
            user = User.find_by(id: user_id)
            if user&.authenticated?(:remember, cookies[:remember_token])
                log_in user
                @current_user = user
            end
        end
    end
```

Comment: `user = User.find_by(id: user_id)` returns `nil`. Then `user.session_token` raises the error.

Answer (score 0):

Change `find_by` to `find_by!`:

```rb
if (user_id = session[:user_id])
       user = User.find_by!(id: user_id)             
       @current_user ||= user if session[:session_token] == user.session_token
```

Comment: it gave me this error when I changed it : 
"Couldn't find User with [WHERE "users"."id" = ?]"

Comment: So, there are probably no user with the given ID. This 'another' question. Did the original problem was solved? I think yes. I suggested you a solution that fixes accessing `user.session_token` in case where `user` is nil that was what you originally asked about.

Comment: "user = User.find_by(id: user_id)"


 >> You should handle the exception as here the user is not present so you're getting an error while fetching 'user.session_token'